# DataSeries method of Range class failed

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run a VB script which performs

1. Add a new column towards left (Position A)
2. Enter value of A1 as "1".
3. Fill down the series incrementing by 1 for all available rows (in Column B).

Actual Code:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("XLSPATH")
Set objSheet = objwb.Sheets("SheetName")
objSheet.Columns("A:A").Insert xlToRight
objSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Record Number"
objSheet.Cells(2, 1).Value = 1
Set Range = objSheet.Range("A2:A"&objSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count) 
Range.DataSeries xlColumns, xlLinear, xlDay, 1, False
objWB.Close True
objExcel.Quit
```

My script is failing at this command throwing error code '800A03EC'

```
Range.DataSeries xlColumns, xlLinear, xlDay, 1, False
```

But similar operation tried through a macro is working fine.

```
Range("A2:A10").Select
Selection.DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Date:=xlDay, _
    Step:=1, Trend:=False**
```

Comment: `I'm trying to run a VB script` Where are you running this from? .Vbs? MS Word? MS Powerpoint? Where?

Answer (score 1):

`Range` is a reserved word in VBA. Please use another name for the variable. Also looks like you are using LateBinding. Have you declared the constants on the top of the code? Try this code (**Untested**)

```
Option Explicit

Const xlUp As Integer = -4162 
Const xlToRight As Integer = -4161     
Const xlColumns As Integer = 2
Const xlLinear As Integer = -4132
Const xlDay As Integer = 1

Sub Sample()
    Dim objExcel As Object
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcel.Visible = True

    Dim objWB As Object
    Set objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("XLSPATH")

    Dim objSheet As Object
    Set objSheet = objWB.Sheets("SheetName")
    objSheet.Columns("A:A").Insert xlToRight
    objSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Record Number"
    objSheet.Cells(2, 1).Value = 1

    '~~> Find Last Row in Col A
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = objSheet.Range("A" & objSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim rng As Object
    Set rng = objSheet.Range("A2:A" & lRow)
    rng.DataSeries xlColumns, xlLinear, xlDay, 1, False

    objWB.Close True
    objExcel.Quit
End Sub
```